# how to check some links that have downloadable file or not (about 1mil links)

Tags: java, android, webview

i had e big challenge...

how can i check link is have a downloadable file or not

example :

http://d88b.ir/upload/jozve-files/1498505490.zip is downloadable

and

http://d88b.ir/upload/jozve-files/1498505489.zip is empty

i must check links from 1498505490 to 1498000000

just i know android studio and webview ...

Answer (score -1):

Use the `HTTP HEAD` command. It will show you the `Content-Length` header which will tell you the size, `Content-type` which will show you the file type, and the HTTP status code (40x for errors such as not found, 20x for success).

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself. **This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity**, accessibility, and recent modification.

Comment: I don't know who voted this down, it's not only correct, it's the only way to do it.

Comment: pls give me code in androidStudio ... i am a bit amatur

Comment: That's not how SO works.  You make an attempt at code, put it in the question, and we will help you.  Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/